# jUnit - test that the object is NOT created in main()

Tags: junit, powermock

This may be a stupid question, as I'm just starting out with jUnit testing, but I need to test that an object of a class is NOT created in the main() method.
Basically, what I need is the opposite of this code I guess:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(Test.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(PowerMockito.mock(Test.class));

Test.main(null);

PowerMockito.verifyNew(Test.class).withNoArguments();
```

The test code above checks that there's a Test object created within the main() method. What I need is a test that scans main() and makes sure that the Test test = new Test() is NOT created there.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, in case anyone runs into the same issue.
Basically, just need to add an extra argument call to never() method within verifyNew(), like so:

```
PowerMockito.verifyNew(Test.class, never()).withNoArguments();
```